# Can I extract coordinate information from biograph object in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have an adjacency matrix without coordinates that I would like to represent nicely using gplot.

I am able to get it to show as a biograph object with a good spacing between all the nodes, so I was wondering if there was a way to extract the coordinates from the biograph object to then use with gplot?

**EDIT:**
I got some negative feedback (with no comments) about this question for some reason, so I will try to elaborate further.

The data I am using is for a graph represented as a weighted adjacency matrix. I would like to be able to display it using the gplot function in MATLAB, however gplot requires cartesian coordinates for each vertex, information that I haven't been given.

I don't really want to have to go to the trouble of using a force directed graph algorithm to calculate the coordinates in order to display the graph, because that would be overkill, I just want a way to display the graph so that the vertices aren't completely randomly distributed.

An easy way to do this is to use the biograph function like so:

```
G = <adjacency matrix>
ids = <vertex labels>

bg = biograph(G,ids,'ShowArrows','off','ShowWeights','on',...
    'EdgeType','straight','LayoutType','equilibrium');

h=view(bg);
```

which displays a reasonable looking representation of the graph, however I would like it if I didn't have to use the biograph environment and I could use the gplot one instead.

The MATLAB documentation says that to find the x-y coordinates of node 3 (for example) I can use:

bg.nodes(3).Position

to query the position of the node; however when do that it returns [ ]

strangely though, if I double click on a node in the graphical representation I can access this information in the pop up window, so I am sure it exists somewhere..

Does anyone have any idea of how I can extract this information from a biograph object? I just need a n*2 matrix with the x and y coordinates for each vertex.

Sorry if my original question was too vague, I hope this is better

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is looking for the answer to this question, the original biograph object does not contain the position information, this is only calculated once the object is viewed - so in order to find the information you need to reference the figure handle, not the original object. This can be done using:

```
h.nodes(3).Position
```